# AutoFit Columns Width using jxl library in java

Tags: excel, width, jxl

is there a way to autofit columns **width** in excel using jxl.jar library in java? 
I'm exporting a JTable into a **.xls** file but the columns don't fit their cells' contents, and I don't know how to set the autofit option. The closest method that I could find is `setShrinkToFit()` but I don't want to shrink the cells' contents, neither to set manually the **AutoFit Column Width** option in Excel every time I create a new one.

Comment: You can read the answer to this other [question][1]

Regards


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665391/jxl-cell-formating

Comment: I found another [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665391/jxl-cell-formating) in StackoverFlow that might answer your question. You can use CellView autosize method.